How can I update multiselect in vue.js?
<form class = "needs-validation" @submit.prevent = "UpdateFormSubmit(holidayObject.id)">
                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <div class = "mb-3">
                            <label for = "validationCustom01">Comments</label>
                            <b-form-input
      
                      id = "validationCustom01"
                            type = "text"
                            class = "form-control"
                            placeholder = "Comments"
                            v-model = "holiday.holidayComments"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class = "mb-3">
                            <label class = "mt-3">Holiday type*</label>
                            <multiselect
                            required
                            id = "validationCustom02"
                            v-model = "holiday.holidayTypeValue"
                            :options = "holidayTypesOptions"
                            placeholder = "select type"
                            selectLabel = "select type"
                            selectedLabel = "selected"
                            deselectLabel = "selected"
                            ></multiselect>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "col-md-12">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <div class = "col-md-12">
                            <div class = "mb-3">
                                <label class="mt-3">Start date*</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                id = "validationCustom03"
                                v-model = "holiday.startDate"
                                type = "date"
                                placeholder = "DD-MM-YYYY"
                                format = "DD-MM-YYYY"
                                autocomplete = "off"
                                ></b-form-input>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "col-md-12">
                            <div class = "mb-3">
                                <label class = "mt-3">End date*</label>
                                <b-form-input
                                id = "validationCustom04"
                                v-model = "holiday.endDate"
                                type = "date"
                                placeholder = "DD-MM-YYYY"
                                format = "DD-MM-YYYY"
                                autocomplete = "off"
                                ></b-form-input>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class = "btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        submit
                    </button>
                </form>

I write a project in vue.js. I have the above form. My problem is that when I make update all fields are updated except holiday type what do I make wrong on this? I try to change the holiday type and debug it and allthough the new holiday type I put is printed to the console the holiday type doesn't change.

Give us your javascript code

I wrote the javascript code below

Isn't that supposed to be <Multiselect /> rather than <multiselect /> ?

The problem is probably in server

You can try to put error message on your question body next time

<script>
import session from "../../../../api/session";
import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";
export default {
 components: {
   Multiselect,
 },
props: {
cardTitle: String,
description: String,
holidayObject: {
type: Object,
required: true,
}
},
data() {
return {
 holiday: {
   startDate: this.holidayObject.holidays_start_date,
   endDate: this.holidayObject.holidays_end_date,
   holidayTypes: [],
   holidayTypeValue: this.holidayObject.holiday_type_name,
   holidayComments: this.holidayObject.comments,
 },
 alertShow: false,
 alertVariant: "",
 alertMsg: ""
};
},
mounted() {
this.fetchHolidayTypes();
},
computed: {
holidayTypesOptions() {
 return this.holiday.holidayTypes.map((e) => e.title);
},
},
methods: {
fetchHolidayTypes() {
session.get("api/holidays/holiday-type-list/").then((resp) => {
 this.holiday.holidayTypes = resp.data;
});
},
UpdateFormSubmit(holidayID) {
if (!this.holiday.holidayTypeValue) {
   alert('select holiday type');
   return;
}
if (!this.holiday.startDate || !this.holiday.endDate) {
   alert('Input the dates');
   return;
}
if (this.holiday.startDate > this.holiday.endDate) {
   alert('end date should be after start date');
   return;
}

const holidayTypesId = this.holiday.holidayTypes
   .filter((e) => e.title === this.holiday.holidayTypeValue)
   .map((item) => item.id)[0];
console.log("holiday type id",holidayTypesId);
console.log("holiday value",this.holiday.holidayTypeValue);
console.log("start date",this.holiday.startDate);
session
   .put(`api/person/holiday/${holidayID}/actions/`, {
       holidays_start_date: this.holiday.startDate,
       holidays_end_date: this.holiday.endDate,
       comments: this.holiday.holidayComments,
       person: this.$route.params.id,
       holiday_type_name: this.holiday.holidayTypeValue
   })
   .then(() => {
       console.log("holiday value then",this.holiday.holidayTypeValue);
       console.log("start date",this.holiday.startDate);
       this.alertShow = !this.alertShow;
       this.alertVariant = "success";
       this.alertMsg = 'Data updated';
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.$bvModal.hide(`Rel${holidayID}`);
           this.$emit("holidayUpdated");
       }, 1500);
   })
   .catch((e) => {
       this.alertShow = !this.alertShow;
       this.alertVariant = "danger";
       this.alertMsg = e.response.data;
   });
},
}
}
</script>

